# Unique Service or Many Service on the ManagedBean

Tags: jsf, architecture, ejb, managed-bean

In my work is used the following pattern: ManagedBeans always have a single Service. When we need to use a different service in ManagedBean, create a method in Service using the Service needed.
But I was wondering if the most correct would be to have all necessary Services injected directly into ManagedBean because I found it very annoying to have to always create methods in the Services only to call other Services. Also apparently it decreases the cohesion of the Service as it will eventually having methods that should not have.

This is the way used in my work.

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserController {

    private User user;
    private List<Job> jobs;

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        users = userService.listAllJobs();
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public List<Job> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void saveUser() {
        userService.save(user);
    }
}

@Stateless
public class UserService{

    @Inject
    private JobService jobService;

    public List<Job> listAllJobs(){
        jobService.listAll();
    }
}
```

This is the way I prefer and also think more correct. Instead of create listAllJobs method in UserService, making it less cohesive, i just injected the JobService into UserController. And that's how I will do with all the services i need for this ManagedBean

```java
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class UserController {

    private User user;
    private List<Job> jobs;

    @Inject
    private UserService userService;

    @Inject
    private JobService jobService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        users = jobService.listAll();
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public List<Job> getJobs() {
        return jobs;
    }

    public void saveUser() {
        userService.save(user);
    }
}
```

i want to use in second way in my work but dont know if is the best way. Please tell me whats the best and the advantages

Comment: You're right. *"ManagedBeans always have a single Service"* makes no sense. For future code review questions, head to http://codereview.stackexchange.com.